# Errors with html checkboxes

Tags: html, checkbox

For some odd reason my checkboxes are coming out like this? No clue why

Here is my code:

```
<div id="prereg">
    <form method="post" action="learn-to-sail.php">
        <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-hide-label">
            <input type="text" id="firstname" placeholder="Sailor's Name">
        </div>  
        <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-hide-label">
            <input type="text" id="lastname" placeholder="Surname">
        </div>
        <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-hide-label">
            <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="E-Mail">
        </div>
        <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-hide-label">
            <input type="text" id="phonenumber" placeholder="Phone Number">
        </div>
        <label for="birthdate">Date of Birth:</label>
        <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-hide-label">
            <input type="date" id="birthdate">
        </div>
        <label>The Sailor Can:</label>
        <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-hide-label">
            <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">I have a bike<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">I have a bike<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">I have a bike<br>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

And here is a screetshot of the outcome:
[image]

This is the only css that is applied other than the default jquery-mobile one:

```
#prereg{
width:60%;
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 800px) {
    #prereg{
        width:100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: We're going to need to see your CSS, as the markup looks fine to me by itself.

Comment: Fiddle it..it looks fine..lol..we need to have a look at your css buddy..

Comment: If I had to take a guess your checkboxes have `position: absolute` so the text doesn't know where to go.

Comment: check my edited code for the css.

Answer (score 0):

Would need to see more code but the following should work for you.

```
input[type='checkbox']{
   margin-right:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have closing tags on your input elements

```
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">I have a bike<br>
```

should be more like:

```
<label><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"/>I have a bike</label>
```